# Avoid non-exhaustive pattern match when using para recursion-scheme

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

Below is some code which I wrote as an exercise for using [`para`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:para) from [`recursion-schemes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) (I know that this reduced example could also be solved using just [`cata`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:cata), but let's ignore this for this question).

While doing this, I noticed that I have to do a non-exhaustive pattern match when I'm using [`para`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:para) if I want to access the expression tree of any of the arguments to the `Depth` constructor.

I found an alternative implementation of `gcata'` and `para'` that don't have this issue, and also don't require a `Comonad`, but just a `Functor` instance on `w`. This makes me wonder: Why wasn't this version used in the implementation of `recursion-schemes`? Is there anything wrong with it, or are there just better ways to achieve what I'm looking for?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Test where

import Data.Functor
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data ExprF a = Depth a a -- ^ Counts the maximum depth of the tree
             | Unit
  deriving Functor
type Expr = Fix ExprF

unit :: Expr
unit = Fix Unit

depth :: Expr -> Expr -> Expr
depth a b = Fix $ Depth a b

evalDepth :: Expr -> Int
evalDepth = cata phi where
  phi Unit = 0
  phi (Depth a b) = max a b + 1

eval :: Expr -> Int
eval = para phi where
  phi Unit = 0
  phi (Depth (Fix (Depth a b), _) _) = evalDepth a + evalDepth b
--            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
-- at this point is the whole *current* expression tree, not just
-- the subtree that was given as first argument to `depth`

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Is this possible without definining gcata' / para' myself with the current API?

eval' :: Expr -> Int
eval' = para' phi where
  phi Unit = 0
  phi (Depth (a,_) (b,_)) = evalDepth a + evalDepth b
--            ^     ^
-- a and b are just the first and second argument to `depth`. No need
-- to do a pattern match which might go wrong.

gcata' :: forall t w a. (Foldable t, Functor w)
       => (forall b. Base t (w b) -> w (Base t b))
       -> (Base t (w a) -> a)
       -> t -> a
gcata' k g = fst . c where
  c :: t -> (a, w a)
  c y = (g x, g x <$ k x) where
    x :: Base t (w a)
    x = fmap (snd . c) . project $ y

para' :: (Foldable t, Unfoldable t) => (Base t (t,a) -> a) -> t -> a
para' = gcata' distPara
```

And here is an example how to use it:

```
eval' (depth (depth unit unit) (depth (depth unit unit) unit)
-- 3
eval (depth (depth unit unit) (depth (depth unit unit) unit))
-- 3
```

As you can see, both functions do the same, calculating the maximum depth of the tree (without counting the most outer `depth` call itself)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`para` is a very very special case.

Notably it uses `(,) (Mu f)` as its choice of `Comonad`.

This `Comonad` has a lot more structure than most.

Notably, it is left adjoint as `(,) e -| (->) e`.

Why does this matter? Well `(,) e` preserves colimits, and thus it only has one `a` inside of it.

So you can get away with `g x <$ k x` -- because you're only replacing one thing!

For any more interesting `Comonad` your `gcata'` should fail.

When you have more than one `a` to replace in `w a`, you're throwing away information, so this won't be a universal recursion scheme.